# Autofilter / Hide rows of cells not containing words from array

Tags: excel, vba, cell, criteria, autofilter

There are 2 sheets in my Excel workbook:
Sheet1: MUFG Client
Sheet 2: Company Information

So basically I want to do autofilter at MUFG Client sheet in "Keyword" field (Field 29) from another cell (I18) in Company Information sheet. And the content of the cell is the result from vlookup formula so it will change and not always be the same. Here goes my vba code:

```
Sub filter_by_cell_value ()
    Sheets("MUFG Client").Range("A2").Autofilter Field:=29, _
    Criteria1:="=Asterixsymbol" & Sheets("Company Information").Cells(18,6).Value & "*", xlOperator:= xlOr
End Sub
```

My objective is I want the autofilter can read the text in cell I18 ***without*** specific text/criteria.

For example, if the cell I18 contains Cosmetics, Chemical --> I want the autofilter in Keyword Field can show the word Cosmetics or Chemical, then

If I change the content of company information sheet into different company (The result of vlookup), the cell I18 in Company Information will change into Food & Beverage, Business Expansion, FMCG--> And I also want the autofilter in the keyword Field (MUFG Client sheet) shows Food & Beverage or Business Expansion or FMCG (Autofiltering contains those words by ignoring order)

And from my vba code above, Cells(18,6) is cell I18 in Company Information Sheet.

Is it possible to do so? I think I have to discuss this directly to make you guys understand. Sorry if this makes misunderstanding.

Thank you so much...

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. What is `Asterixsymbol`?.. So, if the cell I18 contains "Cosmetics, Chemical" then the filter should be "AsterixsymbolCosmetics" or "AsterixsymbolChemical" ?

Comment: @NareshBhople Asterixsymbol means *. It didn't show up so I type manually. Thank you so much fo your reply and correction. I really appreciate it. Well It does work if the keyword field contains Cosmetics or Chemical only. I want to filter not only the first words in cell I18 but also multiple words behind. If the cell I18 "Cosmetics, Chemical", the autofilter can also checklist the cell contains those words like "Cosmetics, Furniture" then "Business Expansion, Cosmetics, Furniture" then "Food & Beverage, Chemical, Properties" by ignoring the order (from the most precise until least precise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this to run automatically on Cells(18, 6) (BTW it is F18 and not I18. Changed it below to make I18) change, then use Calculate event.

if the cell I18 contains "Cosmetics, Chemical" then the filter should be "Cosmetics" or "Chemical" ? Try following

```
Sub filter_by_cell_value()

arr = Split(Sheets("Company Information").Cells(18, 9).Value, ",")

Sheets("MUFG Client").Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

**EDIT** As per comments below, we can hide rows with the following procedure.

```
Sub hide_Rows_by_cell_value()
Dim wb As Workbook, CompInfo As Worksheet, MufgClient As Worksheet
Dim srcCl As Range, lr As Long, FltCol As Range, cl As Range, hideRng As Range
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set CompInfo = wb.Sheets("Company Information")
Set MufgClient = wb.Sheets("MUFG Client")

Set srcCl = CompInfo.Cells(18, 9)
arr = Split(srcCl.Value, ",")

lr = MufgClient.Range("AC" & MufgClient.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set FltCol = MufgClient.Range("AC3:AC" & lr) '2nd Row contains table headers

For Each cl In FltCol
    chk = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    chk = chk + InStr(1, cl.Value, Trim(arr(i)), vbTextCompare)
    Next
    If chk = 0 Then
        If hideRng Is Nothing Then
        Set hideRng = cl
        Else
        Set hideRng = Union(hideRng, cl)
        End If
    End If
Next

hideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Its like "Contains" filter condition which works for two values at time. So it won't be possible with filter if there are more than two values. .. But, yes it is possible with a procedure to hide other rows that don't contain those words

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply & correction. I really appreciate it. Well It does work if the keyword field contains Cosmetics or Chemical only. My objective is I want to filter not only the first words in cell I18 bu also multiple words behind. If the cell from another sheet I18 contains "Cosmetics, Chemical", the autofilter can also checklist the cell contains those words like "Cosmetics, Furniture" then "Business Expansion, Cosmetics, Furniture" then "Food & Beverage, Chemical, Properties" by ignoring the order (from the most precise until the least precise). Is it possible?

Comment: Do you know the VBA code to hide other rows that don't contain those words? Maybe you can change it from my previous VBA code above :)

Comment: Check Answer edited.. If this answers the question please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) with tick / upvote on the left of the answer.

Comment: OHMYGOSH it's Working. Thank you so much for your help. I will accept the answer and the title changed. Cannot do this without you :)